# Can I do this with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

Can I do either of these using LINQ:

**1.** Check that each element in an `IEnumerable<string>` has the correct extension. If not, throw exception.

```
foreach(var filepath in filepaths)
    if(Path.GetExtension(filepath) != @".xml")
        throw new ArgumentException(...);
```

---

**2.** Take an `IEnumerable<string>` and serialise all of its elements into one `string`, with spaces in between each.

```
string args = "";
foreach (var filepath in filepaths)
    args += filepath + " ";
```

Thanks

Comment: So tempted to just answer: "yes" ^^

Comment: @SealedSun If you like downvotes, then go ahead. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (!filepaths.All(x => Path.GetExtension(x) == @".xml"))
{
  throw error;
}
```

`string.Join(" ", filepaths.ToArray())` for the second question.

Comment: I like this better of the two only because All and "==" seems more readable than Any and "!=", but both will do just fine.

Comment: This is a trivial point, but *technically* speaking, this has a functional difference with the OP's code: it will throw if the sequence is empty.

Comment: @Ani you're right, and I'd even say it's not necessarily that trivial either.

Comment: @Ani: You talking about the string.Join? I did not write that, someone edited my answer. .NET 4 supports passing an IEnumerable to string.Join which would not exhibit that behaviour.

Comment: @Ani: An for `All`, it will return `true` if the sequence is empty.

Comment: @leppie: No, about the lack of equivalence of `!All(predicate)` and `Any(!predicate)` . The OP's code can be written as the second, but not the first.

Comment: @leppie: Yes exactly, which is what introduces the difference with the OP's code.

Comment: @Ani: How? It is exactly the same. His code will also not throw an exception if the sequence is empty.

Comment: @Ani: His won't, yours will. Think about it.

Comment: @Ani: I think you are mistaken  :)  `new object[0].All(x => false)` returns `true`. Just look at the code in reflector, it is pretty much identical to the OP's.

Comment: @Ani: LOL, you replied to yourself  ;P

Comment: @leppie: Haha yes, you are right on both counts. I'm afraid the double negations have messed with my head.

Comment: On another note, I think we should delete this 'junk' comment thread, especially since my completely incorrect comment at the top has been upvoted.

Comment: @Ani: Why? I, and I am sure other people, make this mistake all the time  :)

Comment: Yes, but the 'good stuff' will be hidden and the upvoted comment will be at the top. I could write a comment that summarized my mistake so that others will see it. Never mind, your choice.

Comment: Summary - I incorrectly stated that `!All(predicate)` and `Any(!predicate)` would behave differently for empty sequences, but @leppie correctly informed me that this is not the case.

Answer (score 5):

1.

```
if(filePaths.Any(filepath => Path.GetExtension(filepath) != @".xml"))
     throw new ArgumentException(...);
```

2.

```
string args = string.Join(" ", filePaths.ToArray());
```

or, with LINQ (much more inefficient):

```
string args = filePaths.Aggregate("", (combined, path) => combined + " " + path);
```

Comment: Inefficient? Do you have the numbers to back it?

Comment: Linq will be inefficient as string type is immutable and concatenating all the instances using Aggregate will perform poorly in comparison.